# Swashbuckle OData Mapping with EnableUnqualifiedNameCall

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, odata, swagger

I have the following Action

> POST /odata/Individuals({individualId})/Default.SendEmail

Swagger documentation generation using Swashbuckle is setup and configured for OData and documents this correctly.

When I enable Unqualified Name Calls with

```
config.EnableUnqualifiedNameCall(true);
```

the route works correctly with

> POST /odata/Individuals({individualId})/SendEmail

However Swagger still shows the original with the "Default." prefix, and the test no longer works from the Swagger UI.

How can I either allow both Default.SendEmail and SendEmail, or get Swagger to update correctly based on EnableUnqualifiedNameCall?

Answer (score 0):

The same happen to me, the only way I found to solve it was removing the prefix with a regular expression in a documentFilter.

`c.DocumentFilter(() => new SwaggerDocumentFilter());`

```
class SwaggerDocumentFilter : IDocumentFilter
{
    public void Apply(SwaggerDocument swaggerDoc, SchemaRegistry schemaRegistry, IApiExplorer apiExplorer)
    {
    swaggerDoc.paths = swaggerDoc.paths.Select(entry=>
      new {
        key = new Regex(ODataNameSpace + @"\.",
                  RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
            .Replace(entry.key, string.Empty),
        value = entry.Value
     })
    }
}
```

Getting the same namespace set in the property of the ODataConventionModelBuilder object (regretfuly, removing it is not a valid option)